# QGIS (GUI) QNEAT3 Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'

Tags: qgis

I'm using the GUI for QGIS, not writing my own Python script. I'm using the QNEAT3 plugin to create isochrones using the Iso-Area as Polygons (from Point) algorithm. I'm getting the following error when I run the algorithm (screenshot of my parameters is attached):

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/emmaj/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\IsoAreaAsPolygonsFromPoint.py", line 249, in processAlgorithm
polygon_featurelist = net.calcIsoPolygons(max_dist, interval, output_path)
File "C:\Users/emmaj/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Framework.py", line 470, in calcIsoPolygons
band_in = ds_in.GetRasterBand(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'

The parameters attached are what I'm using right now, but I will need to change the size of Iso-area eventually to create different isochrones. However, I've replicated this error with different size values.

How can I fix this error?

[image]